# Copying part of a std::string to another uninitialised string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a C++ function that splits a `std::string` containing a URL into its components. I need to copy the components into this structure:

```
typedef struct urlstruct {
    string protocol;
    string address;
    string port;
    string page;
} urlstruct;
```

Here is the function so far:

```
int parseAnnounce2(string announce, urlstruct *urlinfo){
    int i;

    if(announce.find("://") != string::npos){
        // "://" found in string, store protocol
        for(i = 0; i < announce.find("://"); i++){

        }
    } else {
        // No "://" found in string
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need to copy the characters before the '://' sequence into the urlinfo->protocol string. What is a good way of doing this?

I know that I can't assign it using the following line of code, because the protocol string has not been initialized to contain that memory.

```
urlinfo->protocol[i] = announce[i];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::string::assign`. This should work:

```
if (announce.find ("://") != std::string::npos)
    urlinfo->protocol.assign (announce, 0, announce.find ("://"));
else
    //not found, handle
```

Or, if you want to store the result of `find` in a variable to not calculate/type it twice, you could do that too:

```
std::string::size_type foundPos = announce.find ("://");
if (foundPos != std::string::npos)
    urlinfo->protocol.assign (announce, 0, foundPos);
else
    //not found, handle
```

Comment: You could eliminate the duplicated calls to std::string::find() by storing the value in a variable.

Comment: @Code-Guru, You could, yes. I'd think the compiler would take care of that, though.

Comment: Hmm...that would be interesting to check which compilers, if any, optimize away the function call. Of course, I try not to rely to heavily on compiler optimizations.

Comment: In order to optimize away the `find` call the compiler has to be able to assert that it has no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::insert` should do the job here:

```
size_t pos = announce.find("://");
if(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    protocol.insert(0, announce, 0, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [std::string::substr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). You already have all the information needed by this function.